# Hosting Hugo Website Problems with GitHub

Tags: git, web, netlify, hugo

I have made a website with Hugo and I have used a theme - https://github.com/naro143/hugo-coder-portfolio and my repo for the website are - https://github.com/amannayyar1/AmanPortfolio when I am trying to host the site on netlify it keeps failing and it has to be a problem regarding the theme and submodule not working properly I have been trying for over a week and there is not that much support out there and I really do not know a way of hosting it because it keeps failing because of this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself it was a submodule issue wow which I had to fix by changing a folder name and redirecting it to a folder.